# how dpkg uninstall .deb packages?

Tags: apt, dpkg

how can I clear complete package traces in ubuntu devices?
I am trying to uninstall a package from golang binary. After uninstall when I do dpkg -l /apt-cache  still I am getting package name and configuration files information. Is it possible to remove those traces or uninstall the package using shell script by running script from package maintainer scripts?

Comment: `dpkg -l` queries the dpkg *database*, which includes all known packages, including all uninstalled packages. It's *supposed* to keep track of uninstalled packages.

Comment: I know that please read the question once for a better understanding.

Comment: Did you *remove* the package(s) or *purge* them? the former doesn't remove configuration files (so for example `dpkg -l` may show something like `rc`)

Comment: yes it is showing pc and it was not existing that state. When I run again manually dpkg -P <pakage> command from terminal then traces are clearing.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you used `remove`, which leaves the config files in place.

If you use `purge`, it will also remove the config files.

Neither option will remove data or config files in your /home. You must remove those manually, if any.

Comment: No from the begging I doing purging only. Manually it was working fine.

Comment: Show us the complete output of a `purge` that fails to remove config files. [Add it to your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1223558/edit) above.

Comment: I have implemented one application to uninstall the application based on cloud messages, in that case, I am getting this issue otherwise purging is working fine. So, I can not get that output.

Comment: That is important information that should be in your original question above. Seems like you have a bug in that cloud application.